# Как не дать создавать одинаковые объекты в ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#

У меня есть **ObservableCollection** в которой есть класс содержащий поле **Name** нужно чтобы при попытке задать имя которое уже существует, выскакивало предупреждение. Я пытался реализовать метод **Equals** в классе но в **MainViewModel** но при **Jobs.Contains(value)** получал ошибку связанную с преобразованием.

```
class Job 
    {   
        public  string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
            name = value;
            }
        }
       private string name;
    }
```

```
class MainViewModel 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Job>();
        public ObservableCollection<Job> _Jobs
        {
            get { return Jobs; }
            set
            {
               /* if (Jobs.Contains(value)) 
                {
                    //ошибка
                }*/
                Jobs = value;    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите на `if (Jobs.Contains(value))`, что видите? Я допустим вижу "Если коллекция `Jobs` содержит в себе коллекцию `Jobs`". Может надо не коллекцию, а конкретный объект, который вы где-то добавляете? Вот просто подумайте, включите логику, что у вас тут не так?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как я понял надо в таком случае `if (Jobs.Contains(value[0]))` однако я обнаружил что я даже не попадаю в этот  `set{}` возможно сможете подсказать как это решить грамотно? 
` ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Jobs}" `  ` Binding="{Binding Path = Name}" ` так как я везде иду только в **Name set{}**

Comment: Сделать потомка ObservableCollection с желаемым поведением уникальности? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52192794/5045688

Comment: @Jostario Вы понимаете, что такое свойство? Понимаете, что такое `set`? Вот есть у вас допустим `string Text {get;set;}`, вы в коде пишете `Text = "Привет!";` - у свойства вызывается его `set` (задается значение), если мы его развернем в `set {  ... = value; }`, то в `value` (внутренной переменной свойства) будет `Привет!` (то, что мы задаем свойству). Когда мы пишем `var result = Text;` - вызывается `get` свойства (мы получаем значение). Почему вы думаете, что у вас будет вызыватся `set` свойства коллекции? Вы задаете ей какое либо значение? Например `Jobs = new();`? Нет.

Comment: @Jostario Исходя из выше сказанного, при добавлении в коллекцию чего либо, вы не меняете само свойство, а значит у вас не будет вызова `set`. Теперь смотрим на вашу попытку `if (Jobs.Contains(value))` - у вас `value` это внутренняя переменная свойства, которая является `ObservableCollection<Job>` (самой коллекцией, которую вы пытаетесь проверить), это не объект, который вы добавляете где либо. Теперь как быть с уникальностью - я так понимаю, вы привязали это к `DataGrid`, в которой просто добавляете строки. Если да - то как и сказали выше, пишите свою коллекцию, можете попробовать `HashSet<T>`

Comment: @Jostario `ObservableCollection<T>` нужна тогда, когда вы **в коде** будете писать `Jobs.Add(....)`, без нее у вас попросту не будут появлятся новые объекты в UI, ибо ему не будет идти команда обновления. Поэтому, если пишете свою коллекцию, или используете `HashSet<T>`, подумайте об обновлении. Другой вариант решения - не использовать `DataGrid` для добавления, лишь для отображения. Сделайте нужные поля и кнопку "добавить", при клике на кнопку вызывайте команду, внутри которой будет `if (!Jobs.Contains(value)) Jobs.Add(value);`, все, вы решили свою задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из всех комментариев я бы посоветовал использовать решение предложенное @Alexander Petrov. В случае если вам просто нужно вывести сообщение при добавлении элемента с существующим в коллекции именем, предлагаю использовать  подписку на событие:

```
var model = new MainViewModel();
model.Jobs.CollectionChanged += JobsCollectionChanged;

void JobsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add 
        || sender is not ObservableCollection<Job> jobs 
        || e.NewItems == null) return;
    for(var i = e.NewItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var job = e.NewItems[i] as Job;
        if (job == null) continue;
        if(jobs.Any(j => j.Name == job.Name))
        {
            // Ваше сообщение
        }
    }
}
```